# Reputation Changes in Top-Bar missing entries for removed -1s

Tags: bug

This screenshot shows a minor but interesting bug:

[image]

As you can see, the total reputation change (+1) does not correspond to the entries shown.  The cause is simple - I had given a -1 to an answer, which was subsequently removed, resulting in a +1.  The problem (and it is minor), is that the overall change doesn't appear to match up with what happened in the box.

On the page, you'd see "+1 removed" and a link to the now deleted answer.  Here, it isn't appearing.

Comment: We intentionally don't show deleted post events here - we can take a look at *not* pushing the number delta but that isn't really the intent.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me.  If you convert it, I'll accept it :)

Comment: What about showing "+1 Post deleted" but *not* linking to the deleted post - perhaps link to my profile's reputation page on the stack the post was on?